# Enter key not triggering onClick when tab-navigating div

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, material-ui

I'm trying to make a certain page accessible and allow for interfacing using just the keyboard. The issue that I'm running into is that I have a pseudo-radio selection that operates using React state and the Material UI card elements.

I have an `onClick` listener for each card that updates the state variable and it works fine when I click with my mouse. When I use the tab navigation to select the card and then hit the enter key, it doesn't trigger the click event for some reason.

The specific code in question is as follows:

```js
import {
  Stack,
  Typography,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardActionArea,
} from "@mui/material";

import { useState } from "react";
import { AddOutlined, SyncOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";

export default function CreateAssignment() {
  const [type, setType] = useState<"create" | "assign">("create");

  return (
    <Stack
      direction={"row"}
      alignItems={"center"}
      justifyContent={"center"}
      spacing={4}
      marginY={6}
    >
      <Card
        tabIndex={1}
        sx={(theme) => ({
          width: 200,
          border:
            type === "create"
              ? "5px solid " + theme.palette.secondary.main
              : "5px solid white",
          borderRadius: 6,
        })}
      >
        <CardActionArea onClick={() => setType("create")}>
          <CardContent>
            <AddOutlined style={{ fontSize: 48 }} />
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="body1" fontSize={20}>
              Create A New Device To Assign
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
      <Card
        tabIndex={2}
        sx={(theme) => ({
          width: 200,
          border:
            type === "assign"
              ? "5px solid " + theme.palette.secondary.main
              : "5px solid white",
          borderRadius: 6,
        })}
      >
        <CardActionArea onClick={() => setType("assign")}>
          <CardContent>
            <div>
              <SyncOutlined style={{ fontSize: 48 }} />
            </div>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="body1" fontSize={20}>
              Reassign Existing Device
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```